# react-native bottom navigator does not hide bottomtab totally and it is bumping up

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, chat, stack-navigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Please help me.
I make chat ui.
This problem makes me sick...
Please give me an advice.

My situation is like below

[image]

My Code is like this.
You can understand my code easily..

App.js // BottomTabNavigator SECTION

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    const App = () => {
      const visible = (route) => {
        if (route.state?.index > 0) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
          <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
            <NavigationContainer>
              <Tab.Navigator
                tabBarOptions={{
                  activeTintColor: 'red',
                  inactiveTintColor: 'blue',
                }}>
                <Tab.Screen
                  name={'chat'}
                  component={Chat}
                  options={({route}) => ({
                    tabBarVisible: visible(route),
                  })}
                />
                <Tab.Screen name={'setting'} component={Setting} />
              </Tab.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </>
      );
    };
```

Chat.js // StackNavigator SECTION

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Chat = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="chatlist" component={Chatlist} />
      <Stack.Screen name="chatroom" component={Chatroom} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Chatlist.js

```
const Chatlist = ({route, navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('chatroom')}>
        <Text>chatlist</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Chatroom.js

```
const Chatroom = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <Text>Chatroom</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try drop SafeAreaView

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    const App = () => {
      const visible = (route) => {
        if (route.state?.index > 0) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      };
    
      return (
            <NavigationContainer>
              <Tab.Navigator
                tabBarOptions={{
                  activeTintColor: 'red',
                  inactiveTintColor: 'blue',
                }}>
                <Tab.Screen
                  name={'chat'}
                  component={Chat}
                  options={({route}) => ({
                    // Delete tabBarVisible here ======>
                    // tabBarVisible: visible(route),
                  })}
                />
                <Tab.Screen name={'setting'} component={Setting} />
              </Tab.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Or you can remove tabBarVisible option in 
```
  <Tab.Screen
                  name={'chat'}
                  component={Chat}
                  options={({route}) => ({
                    tabBarVisible: visible(route),
                  })}
                />
```
I found the issue about tabBarVisible  https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5790

Comment: Thanks. But I want to hide bottomTab when user goes into Chatroom..

Comment: ```   <Tab.Screen
                  name={'chat'}
                  component={Chat}
                  options={({route}) => ({
                  })}
                />
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it. but i want to hide tabbar when chatroom screen. That solution makes tabbar remain in all screens..

Comment: I think you are not read note of tabBarVisible is: "Note: Hiding tab bar can cause glitches and jumpy behavior. We recommend the tab navigator inside of a stack navigator instead.". So please check the document https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens

Comment: Thank you so much!! I read it again. It says you are right. So I have to change design. Thank you!